# ACE Reactor quits on interrupted system call

Tags: c++, linux, network-programming, ace, reactor

I have an ACE reactor that accepts socket connections and listens for the incoming data on those connections. The reactor runs in a dedicated thread. This is the thread's entry function:

```
int TcpServer::svc()
{
    LogDebug("The TCP server on %i is running", mLocalAddr.get_port_number());

    // The current thread will own the reactor. By default, a reactor is owned by
    // the creating thread. A reactor cannot run from not owning thread.
    if (mReactor.owner(ACE_Thread::self()) != 0)
    {
        LogThrow("Could not change the owner of the reactor");
    }

    if (mReactor.run_reactor_event_loop() != 0)
    {
        LogWarning("Reactor loop has quit with an error.");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Once in a while `run_reactor_event_loop` exits with -1 and `errno` reports that the reason is "interrupted system call". How can I handle the situation? From what I know I have two options: call `run_reactor_event_loop` again or configure the interrupted call to be called again using `sigaction` and `SA_RESTART`.

1. Is it safe to call `run_reactor_event_loop` again?
2. What does ACE_Reactor::restart method do? It looks like it is supposed to restart the loop? Will it help?
3. How safe it to turn on `SA_RESTART`? Does it mean, for example, that ^C won't stop my application?
4. Are there any other ways to handle the situation?

Comment: Did you take a look at the source code?

Comment: @Peter G., I did. I see that it returns -1 if ACE_Reactor::handle_events() returns -1. Code becomes more complicated there, but I'll try to dig deeper.

Comment: @DumbCoder, this a part of a huge system that has been running without problems. Recently, once in a while, I see the described behavior and I don't have any ideas what could cause it. It seems that no one stops the reactor so what can cause an error?

Comment: I've updated the question. Interrupted system call causes the problem,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how Reactor is constructed. ACE_Reactor::open() cal, takes "restart" parameter (default = false) that tells it to restart handle_events method automatically after interruption.